# How to stop iterator after getting value from database dynamically

Tags: java, jsp

```
<s:iterator  value="menuList" var="quesvar" status="questat">
   <s:hidden name="commonDTO.orgID" id="orgID" value="%{menuList[#questat.index].orgID}"></s:hidden>
   <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="contentDisplay('
      <s:property value="menuList[#questat.index].pagePath" />
      ');" class="">
      <span style="font-weight:bold">
         <s:property  value="menuList[#questat.index].menu"/>
         <strong  style="color: magenta;">
         </strong>
      </span>
      </a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <s:if test="%{menuList[#questat.index].menu == 'Master Data' }">
               <s:iterator  value="menuList" var="quesvar" status="questat">
                  <s:if test="%{menuList[#questat.index].parentMenuID == 3 }">
                     <a href="#" onclick="contentDisplay('
                     <s:property value="menuList[#questat.index].pagePath" />
                     ');">
                     <span style="font-weight:bold">
                        <s:property  value="menuList[#questat.index].menuName"/>
                        <strong  style="color: magenta;">
                        </strong>
                     </span>
                     </a>
                  </s:if>
               </s:iterator>
            </s:if>
            <s:if test="%{menuList[#questat.index].menu == 'Mapping' }">
               <s:iterator  value="menuList" var="quesvar" status="questat">
                  <s:if test="%{menuList[#questat.index].parentMenuID == 4 }">
                     <a href="#" onclick="contentDisplay('
                     <s:property value="menuList[#questat.index].pagePath" />
                     ');">
                     <span style="font-weight:bold">
                        <s:property  value="menuList[#questat.index].menuName"/>
                        <strong  style="color: magenta;">
                        </strong>
                     </span>
                     </a>
                  </s:if>
               </s:iterator>
            </s:if>
      </ul>
   </li>
</s:iterator>
```

I am trying to display menus from database should be come like 
HOME | MASTER DATA | Mapping  | |  |
     (submenus)     (submenus)
getting continuously  | | |  after fetching menus from database as iterator completed values from database.
how stop iterator until gets values from database?